# XSLT: resolve entities providing DTD

Tags: xml, xslt, entity, dtd

I use entities in my XML documents. From these XML document, I want to produce different HTML documents by providing DTDs that resolve the entities in different ways. However, I have to provide a DTD in the XML file so my editor can validate the document.

Can I resolve the entities applying an XSL transformation **regardless of the DTD provided in the XML document**?

XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tes SYSTEM "first.dtd">

&myent;
```

Now I have to DTDs: `first.dtd` and `second.dtd` that resolve the same entities in different ways.

first.dtd:

```
<!ENTITY myent "resolved by first.dtd">
```

second.dtd:

```
<!ENTITY myent "resolved by second.dtd">
```

How could I write two different XSL transformations so that in one case `first.dtd` is used to resolve the entity and in the second `second.dtd` is used?

I tried to provide the DTDs in the XSL transfromations' doctype but always the DTD referenced in the XML document was applied.

Comment: Resolving entities is done by the XML parser so you need to look into the API of your XML parser if it provides a way to set up a custom URI resolver. It has nothing to do with XSLT, other that your XSLT processor uses an XML parser to parse any input documents and/or the stylesheet.

Comment: Thx., I get the point! I will work with tags then and treat them differently in each xsl transformation.

Comment: My suggestion was rather to solve it using e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver(v=vs.110).aspx on the .NET platform or e.g https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html on the Java platform. It all depends on the parser you use and the API it exposes and how you can provide your custom resolver.

Comment: I looked for another solution because my XML files should be usable without any other configuration than provided in the XSL transformations. Now it works the way I want it to because I can process the same tags differently in each XSL transformation. But anyway thank you for your suggestion!